# method run of object iwshshell3 failed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have upload.exe, which should be launched by the button in excel, but when I start from the button, I get an error:

```
method run of object iwshshell3 failed
```

My code

```
Sub upload()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    
    
    Dim strProgramPath As String
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String

      
    strProgramPath = "\upload.exe"
    
    strProgramName = "upload.exe"
    
    strArgument = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    wsh.Run """" & strProgramPath & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
    
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The files in the folder are arranged as follows:

```
directory:
-upload.exe
-table.xlsm
```

Comment: `strProgramPath & strProgramName` will be `\upload.exeupload.exe` which is very likely not what you want. Check `Debug.Print """" & strProgramPath & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """"` and make sure that is the correcd path you want to run. Change to  `strProgramPath = "C:\My\path\to\"` and make sure it ends with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
Dim strProgramPath As String
Const ProgramName = "upload.exe"
Dim strArgument As String
'full path to program in workbook directory      
strProgramPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ProgramName
strArgument = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

wsh.Run """" & strProgramPath & """ """ & strArgument & """", _
  windowStyle, waitOnReturn
...
```